# Django Raw SQL give me TypeError not enough arguments

Tags: sql, django

code:

```
 diary=models.SablogArticles.objects.raw("SELECT articleid,DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(dateline),'%Y-%m')\
 as newtime,count(*) as howmany   FROM sablog_articles group by newtime")
```

The result gave me :

> In template d:\python\project\tpl\base.html, error at line 68 Caught
>   TypeError while rendering: not enough arguments for format string

Answer (score 29):

The raw SQL is a string with formatting parameters, which means that % indicates a parameter to format. Your string has % in it.  You need to double them to protect them from interpretation:

```
diary = models.SablogArticles.objects.raw("""
    SELECT 
        articleid, 
        DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(dateline),'%%Y-%%m') as newtime,
        count(*) as howmany
    FROM sablog_articles group by newtime
    """)
```